# ActiveRecord Collection subtraction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Had a question on subtracting queries from similar ActiveRecord collections.

Let say I have one query that is as follows:

```
all_users = User.all
users_with_adequate_reviews = User.joins(:reviews).select("users.id, count(*) as num_reviews").group(:id).having("num_reviews > 5")
```

if I do `all_users - users_with_adequate_reviews`, I get what I would expect from which is users with fewer than review count of 5. How does ActiveRecord relation subtraction know to remove the similar records even though i only select a few attributes from users (primarily the id). Was looking to see documentation on this but couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WHERE IS SUBTRACTION METHOD DEFINED ?**

Subtraction on ActiveRecord relation is defined on [ActiveRecord::Delegation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L72) module.

If you're digging that source code, you can see that method is delegated from Array class.

So we need to dig Array's subtraction to understand how ActiveRecord relation's subtraction works.

---

**HOW DOES ARRAY SUBTRACTION WORK ?**

This is taken from [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) about Array subtraction / difference.

> Array Difference
>
> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any
>   items that also appear in other_ary. The order is preserved from the
>   original array.
>
> It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.

It means subtraction evaluates two methods : `hash` && `eql?` from each object to perform task.

---

**HOW DO THOSE METHODS WORK ON ACTIVE RECORD OBJECT ?**

The code below is taken from [ActiveRecord::Core](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L421-L437) module.

```
def ==(comparison_object)
  super ||
    comparison_object.instance_of?(self.class) &&
    !id.nil? &&
    comparison_object.id == id
end
alias :eql? :==

def hash
  if id
    self.class.hash ^ id.hash
  else
    super
  end
end
```

You can see both `hash` & `eql?` only evaluates `class` and `id`.

It means `all_users - users_with_adequate_reviews` will exclude some objects **ONLY IF there are any objects from both elements that have same object's id and object's class.**

---

**ANOTHER SAMPLE**

```
irb(main):001:0> users = User.all
  User Load (26.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 11

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:03:45", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:03:45">, 
  #<User id: 2, name: "Danny", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14">, 
  #<User id: 3, name: "Alan", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30">, 
  #<User id: 4, name: "Joe", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00">]>

irb(main):002:0> users_with_multiple_emails = User.joins(:user_emails).select("users.id, users.name, count(*) as num_emails").group(:id).having("num_emails > 1")
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  users.id, users.name, count(*) as num_emails FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_emails` ON `user_emails`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` GROUP BY `users`.`id` HAVING (num_emails > 1) LIMIT 11

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Bob">]>

irb(main):003:0> users - users_with_multiple_emails

=> [
  #<User id: 2, name: "Danny", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14">, 
  #<User id: 3, name: "Alan", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30">, 
  #<User id: 4, name: "Joe", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00">]
```

As you can see `all users - users_with_multiple_emails` excludes first object (Bob).

Why ? It's because `Bob` from both elements have same id and class (id: 1, class: User)

Subtraction returns different result if it's like this

```
irb(main):001:0> users = User.all
  User Load (26.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 11

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:03:45", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:03:45">, 
  #<User id: 2, name: "Danny", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14">, 
  #<User id: 3, name: "Alan", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30">, 
  #<User id: 4, name: "Joe", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00">]>

irb(main):002:0> users_with_multiple_emails = User.joins(:user_emails).select("users.name, count(*) as num_emails").group(:id).having("num_emails > 1")
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  users.name, count(*) as num_emails FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_emails` ON `user_emails`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` GROUP BY `users`.`id` HAVING (num_emails > 1) LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil, name: "Bob">]>

irb(main):003:0> users - users_with_multiple_emails

=> [
  #<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:03:45", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:03:45">, 
  #<User id: 2, name: "Danny", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:04:14">, 
  #<User id: 3, name: "Alan", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:05:30">, 
  #<User id: 4, name: "Joe", created_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00", updated_at: "2020-06-09 13:07:00">]
```

This time `users_with_multiple_emails` only select name & num_emails.

As you can see `all users - users_with_multiple_emails` doesn't exclude `Bob`.

Why ? It's because `Bob` from both elements have different id.

- `Bob`'s id from `users` : 1
- `Bob`'s id from `users_with_multiple_emails` : nil